# Why wont this code allow me to subtract two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have two lists and want to subtract each element from its corresponding element in the opposite list. When I write this code:

`list(map(sub, irrad_fore, irrad_exp))`

I get the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Why is this?

Comment: You cannot subtract a string from a string. Convert the elements of your list to integers, and hen you can subtract them.

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly says, *You can not directly subtract two `str`*. In order to achieve this, you have to firstly convert the `str` objects to `int`. Instead of `map()`, better way will be to write *list comprehension* with `zip()` on both lists as:

```
>>> a = ['1', '4', '7', '9']
>>> b = ['3', '3', '7', '11']
>>> [int(i) - int(j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
[-2, 1, 0, -2]
```